# Are there any easy way to use libraries for hashing data arrays?

Tags: c, hash

I am thinking about using [CRC-32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check#Designing_CRC_polynomials) or [SHA-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1), possibly both in a C program I develop on Linux (Ubuntu).

Are there any easy way to use libraries for either?  Cutting and pasting a CRC-32 algorithm into the source code of my program seems simple enough, but doing the same for SHA-1 feels slightly shaky.  Are there any easy way to use libraries, preferably in Ubuntu but not necessarily?

I am using C, but C++ would be OK if I had to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OpenSSL interface is pretty simple:

```
#include <openssl/sha.h>

unsigned char *SHA1(const unsigned char *d, unsigned long n, unsigned char *md);
```

`d` is a pointer to the input to be hashed, with length `n`.  `md` is a pointer to `SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH` bytes where the SHA1 hash will be stored.

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of free libraries for SHA.
For example this one is great:
http://www.cryptopp.com/ (C++)

Comment: This was seems good too: http://www.crypto-hash.fr/modules/wfdownloads/singlefile.php?cid=13&lid=10

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [LibTomCrypt](http://libtom.org/?page=features&newsitems=5&whatfile=crypt), which is pure C.  You'd have to download, compile and install that, of course.  You'd probably find that the [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/) libraries are already installed - but the interface to those is more complex (more flexible too, but you probably don't need the flexibility).  Offhand, I think they're pure C too.