# SHA-512 source code in C

Tags: c, hash, sha512

Is there any library which implements SHA-512 in C? For example, Linux [sha512sum](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sha512sum). Where can I get it?

Comment: Binged a little found [this one](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=12669&lngWId=3)

Comment: Duplicate?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542412/are-there-any-easy-to-use-libraries-for-hashing-data-arrays

Answer (score 6, accepted):

sha512sum is found in the [GNU Coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/) package

Answer (score 4):

libcrypt ([part of OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/source/)) is an option

Answer (score 4):

[libpolarssl](http://polarssl.org/) has an implementation.

Answer (score 4):

[sphlib](http://www.saphir2.com/sphlib/) has an implementation of SHA-512 in C (and also in Java).

Comment: awesome! sphlib's C implementation of sha512 proved to be 2,5 times faster than coreutils'.

Comment: I see you're a contributor, Thomas ;) Anyway, thanks for the recommendation. sphlib seems to be great!